# display same color of text label as pie chart slice have

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graph, colors, core-plot

i am using core plot to draw pie chart and following text

Error 10
Pass  400

so for above data my pie chart contains 2 slice with 2 different color

i want to set the same text color for each slice

right now text is in white color

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pooja i got it :) try this without implementing

```
-sliceFillForPieChart:recordIndex:
-(CPLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{

CPTextLayer *label = [[CPTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index]];
CPMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [label.textStyle mutableCopy];
textStyle.color = [CPPieChart defaultPieSliceColorForIndex:index];
label.textStyle = textStyle;
[textStyle release];
return [label autorelease];
}
```

Comment: @Samar, do u have any experience to draw Line chart with core plot

Comment: @pooja , i did one before .. what's your question?

Comment: i want to draw Line chart, y-axis with number and x-axis with time, so how to calculate time on x-axis, put x-axis range is 24 hrs cycle, i can plot my line chart with hour now i am confuse how to calculate hr+min+second and draw line

Comment: @pooja, you can follow dateplot example .. i think it will help u

Comment: @pooja, no problem .. let me know if u have any question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `labelTextStyle` property of the plot to change the appearance of the labels.

Comment: ya but how to relate with color as i dont know for which slice which color will be drawn or fill...so as slice have color suppose red so my text color also should be red and other slice have green so text will be green

Comment: i can display label but not same color as slice have, can you give me example of, for same label color as slice have

Comment: You need to implement the `-sliceFillForPieChart:recordIndex:` and `-sliceLabelForPieChart:recordIndex:` methods in your datasource. Use the same color for the fill and for the text style used in your slice label.

Comment: @Eric, following is my code -(CPLayer *)sliceLabelForPieChart:(CPPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
 NSString *test=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[pieValueArray objectAtIndex:pieValueIndex]];
 pieValueIndex++;
 CPTextLayer *label = [[CPTextLayer alloc] initWithText:test];
 CPMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [label.textStyle mutableCopy];
 textStyle.color = [CPColor lightGrayColor];
    label.textStyle = textStyle;
    [textStyle release];
 return [label autorelease];
 
} but still i am not able to see any label even not with  lightGrayColor

Comment: @Eric,i can see label with -(CPLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
 NSString *test=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[pieValueArray objectAtIndex:pieValueIndex]];
 pieValueIndex++;
 CPTextLayer *label = [[CPTextLayer alloc] initWithText:test];//here put values
 CPMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [label.textStyle mutableCopy];
 textStyle.color = [CPColor lightGrayColor];
    label.textStyle = textStyle;
    [textStyle release];
 return [label autorelease];
}
labels are display but only with lightGrayColor